# Retirement plans for my mother

Tags: retirement-plan, spain

My mother has never had a retirement plan (she has worked for years in family houses but that kind of work is often underpaid and doesn't count towards retirement) and now I am very worried about her not having a fund for her coming years. She may be at most 10 years of retiring and she has not thought about this, because she doesn't feel worried about it, but I am. What are my options to start a retirement for her? Can I do that?

I have a ~1.2k income per month and my monthly expenses are approx 400€. I live in Spain

Comment: Your income and expenses are not as relevant as her income and expenses, given she's 10 years away from retiring. Also, please clarify why you believe she's "at most" 10 years away... if she has no savings that would enable her to stop working, she may be "at least" 10 years away.

Comment: I commented my incomes and expenses because I want to start some sort of retirement funds (or an equivalent financial product) for her, because as I expressed in the question, she is not interested in doing it by herself.

Comment: Also, will she be eligible for the Spanish state pension? If so, can she live on it?

Comment: @David I don't think so, but even if she is, I am not sure she will receive enough money from the State to have a decent retirement

Comment: I'm not sure either she's going to have a decent retirement, but (sad to write this) I don't really think she has any manoeuvring chances anymore. Because I don't think a private fund is going to really help her that much. But well, keep gathering opinions, I guess.